# "break" javascript execution

Tags: javascript, execution

I was wondering if there was a way to *break* javascript execution, something like this

```
<script>

if(already_done)
{
  return; //prevent execution (this yields an error)
}

doSomeStuff();

</script>
```

I **know** that this is possible like this:

```
<script>

if(already_done)
{
  // do nothing
}
else
{
  doSomeStuff();
}
</script>
```

But it's not the solution I'm looking for.

Hopefully this makes sense.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Wrap it in a function which immediately executes.

```
(function() {

    if (already_done) { return; }

    doSomeStuff();

})();
```

FYI: `return` is useless without being in a function context.

Also, [this isn't a closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work) since it doesn't return an inner function which uses variables defined in an outer function.

Comment: +1, but how about `(function() { if (!already_done) doSomeStuff(); })();`? ;-)

Comment: @Tomalak - I'm not sure what other things lie in his function, and it's probably best to be consistent with the OP.

Answer (score 3):

Put your code in a closure, like this:

```
(function (){

  if(already_done){
    return;
  }

  doSomeStuff();
})();
```

It should work.

Comment: This isn't necessarily a closure, it is an anonymous function though.

Comment: @Nick Craver: When is it *not* a closure?

Comment: @Tomalak: A closure is when you return a function inside of another function, and in the inner function you're binding variables defined in the outer function per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/111102/how-does-a-javascript-closure-work

Comment: @Tomalak - when nothing inside is it exposed to the outside, creating a linkage of sorts between internal an external members, "closing" off part of it, e.g. if it had `window.var = somethingInHere` and that referenced other things, it'd be a closure.  There's often confusion around this, Closure != scoping != anonymous method, there's a lot of overlap, but they're not synonymous.

Comment: @Nick Craver, @meder: Okay, fair enough.

Answer (score 3):

You have one option directly in a `<script>` block: you can throw an error, but this usually isn't desirable in the middle of a block of code...

```
if(already_done){
  throw "Uh oh";
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about that but I'm trying to avoid throwing an error (since it's technically not an error in my case)

Comment: @Pablo - If your case is general and directly in a block isn't a constraint, then I'd go the anonymous function route like @madeinstefano has above.

Comment: Yes I'll guess I'll do that. Thanks anyway @Nick

Answer (score 0):

What would 'already_done' be? a boolean?
it sounds to me like a loop... can you use something like?:

While ( !already_done )
{
  doSomeStuff();
}

Comment: Not really. It would be more like the presence of a namespace that I've created in the `doSomeStuff()` function

Answer (score 0):

You could use `break` with a `label:`

```
<script>

testcase:
if (already_done) {
    break testcase; //prevent execution
}

doSomeStuff();

</script>
```

though, as stated in other answers, wrapping it in a function is your best method.

Comment: This makes code hard to follow. If you want  to halt to script, wrap everything in a self calling function